# Unable to access Heroku environment config in dropwizard yaml config file

Tags: heroku, dropwizard, heroku-postgres

I have implemented simple REST API using Dropwizard and trying to launch it on Heroku.
I am stuck at the point where I want to access postgresql DB on Heroku.
I am not able to access the configuration on Heroku.
I have config vars set on heroku as below:

```
 $ heroku config
 HEROKU_DATABASE_URL:<some value>
 HEROKU_DATABASE_USERNAME:<some value>
 HEROKU_DATABASE_PASSWORD:<some value>
```

I am accessing them in my dropwizard app along with other config settings in config.yml as:

```
database:
  driverClass: org.postgresql.Driver
  user: HEROKU_DATABASE_USERNAME
  password: HEROKU_DATABASE_PASSWORD
  url: jdbc:postgresql:HEROKU_DATABASE_URL
```

I have also tried :

```
System.getenv("HEROKU_DATABASE_USERNAME")
```

But none of these work.

If I substitute with actual values my service works.

Can somebody point me to the correct way of resolving/accessing config settings from heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dropwizard lets you pass in configuration options on the command line with -D flags as well (See the note [here](http://dropwizard.codahale.com/manual/core/#configuration)), so in your Procfile you can start your server with `java -Ddw.database.user=$HEROKU_DATABASE_USERNAME ... -jar app.jar server` to use the environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, yes I can pass the configuration options using -D that works. But I would prefer the yaml configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a little add-on for dropwizard, that allows you to reference environment variables in your config.yml file. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tkrille/dropwizard-environment-config). It works by specifying `$env:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE[:DEFAULT_VALUE]` as value for array elements or object fields in your yaml file.

Comment: tkrille Looking at your add-on, how do you get to the properties in the YAML file from within the Java code?

Comment: @BSB you can retrieve the properties by the usual means, i.e. just get them from your application's configuration instance. the only thing my add-on is doing, is parse all the `$env:...` stuff before system property replacements are taking place. see also [here](https://github.com/tkrille/dropwizard-environment-config/blob/master/src/main/java/de/thomaskrille/dropwizard/environment_configuration/EnvironmentConfigurationFactory.java#L127).